# What type(s) and dimensions are necessary for the customdata field in a Plotly heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I have successfully created a Plotly heatmap (in Python). I am now trying to add to the `customdata` field. According to [their documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#heatmap-customdata), this field exists for heatmaps and can be a List, Numpy array, or Pandas series. If my `x` component is length *m* and my `y` component is length *n*, shouldn't my custom data be a list of *n* lists that are length *m*? (aka it should mirror the shape of my data) I'm even passing my `z` component into `customdata` (which should be the exact rigth dimensions) and there is still nothing present in the customdata field. Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!

Example code:

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Heatmap

# assume xlabels, ylabels, zdata, etc. all exist and are correct

trace_heatmap = go.Heatmap(
    x=xlabels,
    y=ylabels,
    z=zdata,
    customdata=my_list_that_works_correctly_for_text,
    colorscale=colorscale,
    text=my_list_that_works_correctly_for_text,
    hoverinfo=‘text+x+y’)
```

Everything apart from the `customdata` does what it should. The heatmap shows up, the labels are correct, when I hover it shows what I want, the color scale is correct. But on a click event that is supposed to return x, y, z, text, and `customdata`, it does not even have a field for customdata. If it matters, again, I am using Python, and using Plotly and Dash (which is made by Plotly). This [example](https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started-part-2) in the Graph Crossfiltering section shows a functional version with scatter plots instead of a heatmap. Below is what I get when I trigger a click on a cell of the heatmap, with `customdata` notably absent.

`{'points': [{'curveNumber': 0, 'x': '1', 'y': '2', 'z': 3, 'text': 'Households: 4'}]}`

Comment: What do you mean with 'nothing present in the customdata field'? You cannot access the data in your JS plot?

Comment: I'm using it in Python, and if I try to access the customdata for any given point, I get a key error, saying that for the data associated with that point, there is no customdata. Since it isn't there, I would assume that I am not putting it in correctly.

Comment: Please add the code you are using and the error you are getting in order to have a minimal working example.

Comment: I just updated the post, I hope that helps explain my issue. It might be of use to know that I am using Dash by Plotly. I am not getting an error message per se, but it is not functioning as I would expect.